# How can I display an icon within a Vuetify 3 v-list-item

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How can I display an icon within a Vuetify 3 v-list-item since v-list-item-icon has been removed in Vuetify 3? I have the following code, and I want to add an icon (e.g., 'mdi-file-tree') next to the title. What's the recommended approach to achieve this in Vuetify 3?"

```
 <v-list-item>
   <v-list-item-title>Users</v-list-item-title>
   <v-list-item-icon>
     <v-icon>mdi-file-tree</v-icon>
   </v-list-item-icon>
 </v-list-item>
```

I tried many things but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the output?Then  ```<v-list-item-icon>``` is vuetify2., so remove it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [examples from the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#density)? Almost all of them use icons...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list/#slots-append) in Vuetify 3.

`<v-list-item-icon>` in vuetify 2.

And, `v-slot:prepend` in vuetify 3.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNUstu2zAQ/BWDZ1NM4aIHwzXSFjm0h7bo4xTloIhrmwlfIFeyi8D/3iUZq7LdPG7a2dXszCyvH1gMrfjgfdV3wOZsgWC8bhCWtZ1MFj1vmyAnptnxrZK4eV+z2cVFzXI397WK+FgNNVfEMoDHMEeFGpa/I4S4EOeN0V8HKZOeR+1w7gN4sHI0kqlV6+zSSMVXSgPHAJB4MzoiE0fGCnSu9oAV91Qk+1SMfmdTppW9j9VddJYSe0ijNWtjrNl8cl14arZB9HEuRCstTUrQqg+VBRTWG0FZo1r9uZxVs+rNOyFp4wHjurmNVWZLVDe13dNGZbwLyE3jT9aWRl6dkYQRU6pf0HBJYyJ0FpUBLp3JYt4WLSO4gmj4bXBbOhiR1Gw6WpMEv2LVi3Zpxxm3oIU9BB7o5BAgvNbSyW9jWyetM2tp+74EjpHez0qtT6/sjKdXFr55VM4ex95o7bZfMoahg8FLu4H2/j/4XdwVT98DZGUj/9iENWBpX/38Cjv6HprGyU4/nviJ5g+ITndJYxn72FlJskdzWe3n/HqUXf+KVzsEGw+mktCcRp7P9/j0jPV/cintIcX9lOXwKc5yeXbzF5Y9cvc=)